# grab text in emeditor from external windows potplayer application

Tags: emeditor

i can copy complete playlist along with path from the potplayer playlist using `control+a` followed by `control+alt+c` commands. potplayer is available at the following address

`C:\Program Files (x86)\The Kmplayer\PotPlayerMini64.exe`.

Is it possible to grab text from the above player from emeditor macro code? Is it possible to send messages to external windows and from there get the text copied to emeditor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure about the potplayer you are using. However, If you know the window title or class name of the window where you want to send the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> keys, you can write a similar code like this:

```
wnd = shell.FindWindow( "", "potplayer window title" );
wnd.SetForeground();
shell.SendKeys( "^a" );
Sleep( 100 );
shell.SendKeys( "^%c" );
```

If you don't know the window title or class name, but running the app path "C:\Program Files (x86)\The Kmplayer\PotPlayerMini64.exe" activates the window, you can run this:

```
WshShell = new ActiveXObject( "WScript.Shell" );
WshShell.Run( "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\The Kmplayer\\PotPlayerMini64.exe" );
Sleep( 1000 );
shell.SendKeys( "^a" );
Sleep( 100 );
shell.SendKeys( "^%c" );
```

**References**

- FindWindow: http://www.emeditor.org/en/macro_shell_find_window.html
- SendKeys: http://www.emeditor.org/en/macro_shell_send_keys.html

Comment: sir when i changed the upper case to lower case , the script started working. thanks a lot. my modified code is wnd = shell.FindWindow( "", "Playlist" );
wnd.SetForeground();
Sleep( 1000 );
shell.SendKeys( "^a" );
Sleep( 1000 );
shell.SendKeys( "^%c" );
thestr = clipboardData.getData("Text");
Editor.newfile();
Testdoc = Editor.activedocument;
Testdoc.write(thestr);
document.selection.Copy(eeCopyUnicode);  // copy the seleciton to the Clipboard   can you suggest any improvement in the above code?

Comment: What improvement? Please make it a separate new question, and clarify your question.

Comment: in your code, you have not pasted the grabbed text to emeditor window? otherwise your code is working perfectly. manually i have to press paste button on emeditor toolbar to copy the clipboard contents. you have partially answered my question.("from there get the text copied to emeditor?")

Comment: I didn't know "grab" meant "paste". You should have clarified your question. To paste the clipboard content to EmEditor, `document.selection.Paste(eeCopyUnicode);`  Please first consult Help, or use **Start/Stop Record** on the **Macros** menu of EmEditor if you don't know.

Comment: document.selection.Paste(eeCopyUnicode); is pasting the previously copied data also. i have to run the macro code twice to copy the current clipboard data. some problem with paste command.

Comment: I am not sure why, but maybe you might want to insert `Sleep(500);` before the paste to wait for 500ms or so.

Comment: excellent. Sleep(500); trick worked for me. thanks a lot.